# Matching one of two fields with $in and $elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Combining $in and $elemMatch

I'm trying to find a partial match for an employee's first or last name. I tried using the $or operator, but Mongo doesn't seem to recognize it.

Where am I going wrong?

```
router.get('/employees', async (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.query.name) {
    const response = await Companies.find({ employees: 
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          $in: [
            { first_name:new RegExp(req.query.name, 'i') },
            { last_name:new RegExp(req.query.name, 'i') }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
    res.json({ response })
  }
  else { next() }
})
```

My schema looks like this:

```
const companies = new mongoose.Schema({
    company: [{
        name: { type:String, required:true },
        contact_email: { type:String, required:true },
        employees: [{ 
            first_name:String,
            last_name:String,
            preferred_name:String,
            position: { type:String },
            birthday: { type:Date },
            email: { type:String },
         }],
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }
})
```

I have some names in there that should match (including just "nna"),  but sending a get request to /employees?name=nna just returns an empty response array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most convenient way to get employees back would be to unwind and then match like so:

```java
db.Companies.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$employees"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "employees": "$employees",
        "_id": 0
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "employees.first_name": /anna/i
            },
            {
                "employees.last_name": /anna/i
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

on the other hand, if the goal is to get the companies back, then this would work:

```java
db.Companies.find({
    "employees": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "first_name": /anna/i
                },
                {
                    "last_name": /anna/i
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```